# Is Linux able to perform any kind of Measured Boot?

Tags: boot-loader, malware, tpm

Some Linux-distro's support Secure Boot. (These distro's use a 1st-stage bootloader signed by Microsoft.)

Is Linux (without any additional modules) able or is there any Linux-distro out there that is able to also perform *any kind of Measured Boot using a TPM* alongside Secure Boot?

Comment: *Measured boot* is a microsoft term. The Linux equivalent is IMA [Integrity Measurement Architecture](http://linux-ima.sourceforge.net/) developed by IBM, which has been around since kernel 2.6.30, or about 2004.

Comment: @meuh Thanks! [IMA](http://linux-ima.sourceforge.net/) requires a TPM. Let's say i enter UEFI setup and clear the TPM before doing a clean install of Linux, then what happens? Will [TrouSerS](http://trousers.sourceforge.net/) initialize the TPM automagically (during installation) such that [IMA](http://linux-ima.sourceforge.net/) can make use of it?

Comment: This is a complex subject about which I know little, and it has moved on since I last looked at it. You need to study a whole lot of documentation to understand the security implications of each step and even know what questions to ask.  Installation is not necessarily the most important part, as each bootup to the kernel and application has to verifiable, independently of how you got there. Ubuntu was the distribution that talked most about secure boot, so perhaps you can start there; eg strongswan says [14.04 LTS](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IMA) has an IMA kernel.

Comment: "Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is one of the few Linux distributions which have IMA capability already compiled into their Linux kernel (CONFIG_IMA=y). [**This has the advantage that no special kernel must be built which can become quite involved if you intend to use IMA in conjunction with Secure Boot requiring a signed kernel.**](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IMA) With Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, activating IMA in the kernel is a piece of cake; just add the boot option `ima_tcb` to the `/etc/default/grub` configuration file."

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know.

Comment: Secure Boot seems to only care about *executables*. Because the GRUB configuration file does not contain executable binary code, it is not subject to Secure Boot restrictions. Adding boot options to `/etc/default/grub` only affects the `grub.cfg` configuration file: it does not cause the executable part of grub to be modified.